# Ajax CORS alternatives

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, browser, cors

I have an REST API Service on domain api.example.com. And want to use this api also for my javascript ajax Requests on www.example.com.

I build my jQuery AJAX Requests (GET, POST, PUT and DELETE) using CORS, and on firefox and chrome all works fine. I tested the script on Opera and nothing loaded. After this, I read some online Articles and have to realize that CORS not work with Opera.

What alternatives there are to Get and Put Data to the Rest Service? JSONp don't work, because I need the other HTTP Verbs (POST, PUT, DELETE) too.

Create an "tunneling" php-Script on same domain? But than, I have much more Network traffic and Serverload.

```
Client -> WWW-Server -> API-Server
API-Server -> WWW-Server -> Client
```

instead of

```
Client -> API-Server
API-Server -> Client
```

I'm thankfully for every Idea which will be shared with me.

Comment: I think you covered all of the options (CORS, JSONP, proxying).

Comment: I don't check but Opera 12 supports CORS: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/dom-access-control-using-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

Comment: The actually stable Version of Opera is 11.xx and doesn't support CORS. But I also want to support this Version (and of course the users) and looking for an workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use third-party tools for tunneling, for example [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/).

> The Yahoo! Query Language is an expressive SQL-like language that lets you query, filter, and join data across Web services.

YQL would act as a middleman to wire up calls from your site to your API. The network traffic would look like this:

```
Client -> YQL -> API Server
```

which looks fine to me.

YQL has been around for quite a long time. Their [free quotas](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/usage_info_limits.html) are favorable and uptime is pretty good, too:

> - Per IP limits: /v1/public/*: 2,000 calls per hour; /v1/yql/*: 20,000 calls per hour.
> - YQL has a performance uptime target of over 99.5%.

Moreover, quotas are constantly increasing and Yahoo! provides certain guarantees that if they decide to shutdown the service they'll keep it running for quite a while so you'll have time to migrate. There are several projects that use YQL today (I'm aware of one such service - [TipTheWb.org](http://tiptheweb.org/))

In addition I suggest you to detect whether a given browser supports CORS and fallback to YQL only if necessary:

```
function browserSupportsCors() {
    if ("withCredentials" in new XMLHttpRequest())
        return true; // most browsers
    else if (typeof XDomainRequest == "object")
        return true; // IE8+
    else // Opera currently here, but they'll get better pretty soon :)
    return false;
}
```

or if you use jQuery it has a neat [`support`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) method.

```
if (!$.support.cors) {
    // YQL fallback
}
```

There are also great [tips to tweak YQL performance](http://www.slideshare.net/cheilmann/using-yql-sensibly-yuiconf-2010).

---

*Thank you for caring about Opera users!*

Comment: I have read some Getting Started articles and YQL looks interesting, but unfortunately very different from jquery.ajax, too. I have much LOC AJAX and result logic and don't want to rewrite all the code, is there an jQuery Plugin or so where I can switch the request only? So the success/error, headers, parts are the same? (I have Authentication Headers to send to my api servers)

Comment: YQL has this concept of Tables. These are small xml documents that describe your API. You should play with YQL Console, YQL Editor and YQL Lint. Linter is particular valuable since you can test your own tables with it. You can use YQL to securely stor your API keys (read more about it at http://derek.io/blog/2010/how-to-secure-oauth-in-javascript/).

Comment: As for rewriting your AJAX calls. In jQuery you have a really great hook for such cases: `$.ajaxPrefiller(function (options) { /* check if current browser doesn't support CORS and change the options.url to YQL versions if that's the case */})` Put it once before making any cross-domain requests and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The most common solution is indeed using a proxy script on your server.

The bandwidth is most likely negligible - we are talking about small requests, not huge downloads after all.
And the server load is also minimal - and you could always use something asynchronous and lightweight such as node.js to reduce the load even more.