# Why jQuery ajax jsonp request gives error?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, datatables

```
"fnServerData": function( sUrl, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
            oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
                "url": sUrl,
                "data": aoData,
                "success": fnCallback,
                "error":function(msg){
                    alert(msg);
                },
                "dataType": "jsonp",
                "cache": false
            } );
        },
```

When I make that request, server gives that response.

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: application/javascript
Expires: Thu, 12 Jul 2012 06:23:18 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 12 Jul 2012 06:23:18 GMT
Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie
```

And a json data in Response body.

But ajax code says it has an error, and going into "error" code block.

Why it is giving error while its status is 200?

UPDATE:

In Django server code:

```
            response_dict = {}                
            response_dict.update({'aaData': aaData})
            response_dict.update({'sEcho': sEcho, 'iTotalRecords': iTotalRecords, 'iTotalDisplayRecords':iTotalDisplayRecords, 'sColumns':sColumns})
            response = HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_dict), mimetype='application/javascript')
```

Comment: Can you show the real value of sUrl?

Comment: /category/list/ is sUrl.

Comment: @Burak, I've updated my answer, check if it works for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the server response contain JSON with padding?

You see, there are two ways to receive data from different domain:

1. [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) is the new one but requires a separate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to be sent from the server. Browser support is also somewhat limited for it.
2. [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) doesn't rely on a server header but instead requires it to send back JSON data with so-called *'padding'*:

   ```
   callback('{"your": ["json", "data"}')
   ```

   Your JavaScript library (jQuery in this case) is then wraps it into a new `script` tag tricking your browser to evaluate it. Inside this `callback` function jQuery parses the JSON data and sends it to your `fnCallback`. After that it removes the unnecessary `script` tag from the page. In general it's a very fragile solution but it works in practice. For example, if the server doesn't pad JSON data you'll end up with the following code inside a `script` tag:

   ```
   '{"your": ["json", "data"}'
   ```

   Notice that it's just a string and does nothing. So, check if the server sends the wrapped JSON and not the raw JSON. I've run into the same problem quite a few times before and that helped me.

---

**EDIT**: Since you posted your server-side code I assume that you can modify it. I've never played with Django but I'll try to give you hints:

1. Inside the `request` that you receive there should be a parameter called `callback` - that's what jQuery sends to you and what you should use for padding. Put it somewhere:

   ```
   # Like I said I don't know the exact API but you get the idea
   callback = request.GET["callback"]
   ```
2. After that *pad* your response before sending it to client:

   ```
   response = HttpResponse( # Put callback name before the actual JSON
                  callback + "(" + simplejson.dumps(response_dict) + ");", 
                  mimetype='application/javascript')
   ```

This should work.

Comment: Last-Modified: Thu, 12 Jul 2012 07:30:54 GMT
Expires: Thu, 12 Jul 2012 07:30:54 GMT
Content-Type: application/javascript
Cache-Control: max-age=0

{"sColumns": "id,name,description,image_path,sort_order,parent,", "iTotalRecords": 12, "aaData": ...  is the response coming from server.

Comment: Ah, you see here: `...  {"sColumns": ...` _no padding_ before the server response data :( If it's your server then you should modify the server-side code to support padding. If it's not yours, try CORS, or ask them to add JSONP support, or use some server-side querying solution. [See my answer about the later](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580765#10581382).